# Read integers from a file into array

Tags: c++

I have a file like so:

```
1 20 42 45 ...(74 integers)
2 43 41 92 ...(74 integers)
```

There are 74 rows of 74 integers each separated by spaces.

The following code is not working for me:

```
#define NUM 74
int info[NUM][NUM] = {0};
std::ifstream file("file.txt");
std::string line;
int i = 0, j;

while(std::getline(file, line)){
    for(j=0; j<NUM; j++){
        std::istringstream(line) >> info[i][j];
    }
    i++;
}
```

This code stores only the first value of each row into each of the 74 columns of info[i].
I know if I had a list of say 2 integers per row, i could use:
    std::istringstream(line) >> info[i][0] >> info[i][1] 
But I am not sure how to do this for high number of integers (like 74).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the `std::istringstream` for each line outside the inner loop and re-use it inside the inner loop.

```
while(std::getline(file, line)){
    std::istringstream line_stream(line);
    for(j=0; j<NUM; j++){
         line_stream >> info[i][j];
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, similar to what i figured out

Answer (score 2):

Since you already know you read integers, you can use formatted input like this:

```
std::ifstream in("text.txt");
int values[74][74];

for (int i = 0; i < 74; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 74; ++j)
        in >> values[i][j];
```

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out how to do it.

need alter the while loop like so:

```
while(std::getline(file,line)){
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    int val;
    j = 0;
    while(iss >> val){
        info[i][j] = val;
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: +1 This method is actually preferable to using string streams.

Comment: You don't need `val` just do `while(iss >> info[i][j]){`