# Read ints from file into 3D array

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

The following is a snippet of the file I have:

```
23 //clump1.A
45
21

24 //clump1.B
235
212


2315 //clump2.A
123
14

1234 //clump2.B
213
123
213


3112 //clump3.A
323
4214
```

I've shown roughly 3-4 in each "clump", however there are 74 numbers in each clump. There are 2 "clumps" for each double paragraph separated clumps of numbers, for which there are 4192 larger clumps.

I need the following array to be constructed:

```
int array[4192][2][74],
```

for example, `array[2][0][1] = 3112` from the above example.

How can I read this file in and get them in the correct spots of the array. Using `istringstream` gives me a seg fault.

I am using similar code as [Read integers from a file into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221490/read-integers-from-a-file-into-array)

Please let me know if I should elaborate.

```
while(std::getline(file, line)){
    std::istringstream input(line);
    for(j=0; j<2; j++){
        for(k=0; k<NUM_REGIONS; k++){
            input >> history[i][j][k][0];
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

With this, how can I skip over new line characters, and ensure two new line characters in a row causes i++ to occur.

Comment: I'm not seeing the logic in `array[2][0][1] == 3112`. Can you explain?

Comment: It's just assignment of value to correct cell. 3112 is in the third "clump" (hence 2), first sub-clump (hence 0) and taking first number. Well indeed, that one should be 0 too, unless that part of array isn't indexed from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just count new lines with a flag?

ie:

```
input >> tmp;
if tmp == /n
    flag++;
if flag > 2{
    flag = 0;
    i++;
    continue;
}
history [][][] = tmp
```

That may not be exactly want you want but u can modify ...
Or am i misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 0):

First of all note that in getline:

> If the delimiter is found, it is extracted and discarded.

In this case delimiter is '\n', so to check whether empty line was read you have to simply check if `line` is empty. Then you can use modulo with some integer in order to count them.

```
while(std::getline(file, line)){
    if(line.empty()) {
        ++n;
        n %= 2;
        if(n == 0) ++i;
    }
    else {
        std::istringstream input(line);
        for(j=0; j<2; j++){
            for(k=0; k<NUM_REGIONS; k++){
                input >> history[i][j][k][0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```